# Java 8: Random selection of List using Random.LongStream()

Tags: java, random, collections, java-stream

Is there a way to get a random selection of items (no repeats) from a stream if you give it a Random.IntStream()?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to select the same element multiple times?

Comment: You have asked two questions. Please edit your question so you are asking only one question. See [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Something like this `Random.ints(0, items.size()).distinct().map(n -> items.get(n));`?

Comment: @Bohemian Where's the second question? I see only one. He asked a question, and gave an explanation of why he asked it.

Comment: @marstran no, there are two largely unrelated questions - one per sentence. The first question deals with getting an unrepeating "selection" (size limited? not stated) of elements from a `Random.IntStream()`. The second deals with getting a random selection of 10 elements from a 1000 element ArrayList (no mention of repeating).

Comment: @Bohemian Huh? His first sentence ends with a question mark, and the second with a period. Also, they are not unrelated because the answer to the question is easily used to get 10 elements randomly from a list. Are you basing this on the minor detail that he didn't mention the word "repeating" in the second sentence?

Comment: Well, hopefully my comment helped him. I think it was way to strict to close this question.

Comment: @marstran the solution to selecting 10 random elements from a list cannot be used to make a selection of non-repeating elements from an IntStream.

Comment: @Bohemian It's the other way around. Getting a selection of non-repeating elements from a random IntStream _can_ be used to get 10 random elements from a list.

Comment: These are the same question.  The second sentence is simply an example.

Comment: @Bohemian, you are not helpful and you've wasted people's time.

Comment: @GuyFawkes Please precisely define what “selection” means. Is it a certain quantity? Is it some qualitative filter? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an array list of 1000 `Foo` objects and you need to pick 10 elements randomly from this list, it is possible to use [`Random.ints(int origin, int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) to get an "infinite" stream of random indexes in the list and then pick up the needed elements by the index:

```java
List<Foo> largeFooList = List.of(...); // 1000+ Foo objects

List<Foo> lucky10 = new Random() // or ThreadLocalRandom.current()
    .ints(0, largeFooList.size())
    .distinct() // ensure all the ids are different
    .limit(10)
    .mapToObj(largeFooList::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```